# como enviar al usuario a la pagina inicial si no estan logueados usando sessions>

Tags: php, javascript, html

estoy haciendo un login simple, donde el usuario pone los datos y lo lleva al panel, pero lo que quiero hacer es que si otro usuario quiere entrar a ese panel no pueda acceder si no esta logueado.

si ustedes saben, favor de ayudarme.

validar:

```html
<?php

$miuser = "root";
$mipass = "1234";

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
 $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
 $pass = $_POST['password'];
 if ($usuario == $miuser and $pass == $mipass ) {
        if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
         setcookie('usuario', $usuario, time()+60*60*7);
         setcookie('passowrd', $pass, time()+60*60*7);
        } 
        session_start();
         $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
         header("location: feed.php");
    } else {
     echo "usuario o clave son incorrectos";
    }
} else {
 header("location: login.php");
}

?>
```

panel del usuario:

```html
<?php 
session_start();
echo "Bienvenido" . $_SESSION['usuario'];
echo "<a href='salir.php'>salir</a>"
?>
```

salir.php

```html
<?php

session_start();
session_destroy();
echo "has salido correctamente";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

agrega esto tu pagina del panel, en la parte superior en un script de php

```
session_start();
if( !isset( $_SESSION["usuario"] ) ){
    header("Location: login.php");
}

   // codigo de tu panel
```

valida si existe la variable session 
espero haberte ayudado